# PayPal Android SDK not working with India Currency INR

Tags: android, paypal-rest-sdk

```
Parcelable payPalPayment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(170.0d), "INR", "Premium", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);  
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);  
intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);  
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payPalPayment);  
startActivityForResult(intent, 200);
```

I  have created the app from developer paypal and have added the correct code in android studio,but I couldn't see any paypal checkout after running.The USD(united states) works well.
PayPal is in India.

Comment: check paypal sdk documentation is it provide INR currency or not

Comment: they say that it is provided.

Comment: ask to PayPal help desk to integrate payment gateway using INR currency or not

Comment: did you get solution?

Answer (score 0):

PayPal integration for India works differently, Please make sure your account is KYC verified with PayPal. please call Help Center - PayPal to help you on this.
Call 1800 419 9833 (only for India)

For the Android documentation please refer the below [github](https://github.com/santhoshlfms/Android_PayPal_EC_CustomTab_Demo) and [PDF guide](https://github.com/santhoshlfms/Android_PayPal_EC_CustomTab_Demo/blob/master/PayPal_Express_Checkout_AndroidCCT.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

As the document (https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK) mentions android SDK is deprecated and hence there are no updates.And yes it supports for INR currency and PayPal is India as well.
But the deprecated version doesnt support for Domestic Currency (INR) and for new Integration it is not advised to go for this SDK (depreacted), instead you can use REST API method for Integration with Custom Chrome Tab Implementation for apps. Please note that if you have Indian Business Account make sure that your KYC is verified to receive payments in INR currency,as India customers having Indian PayPal account can make payments only in INR.